# What's the best method of making a [chalk] board sturdy?

Tags: wood, adhesive, frame

I bought a chalk board and arrived today. It is a great surface, but on a 1/8 inch Masonite board. I need to attach this to a wall, but it is very flimsy and writing on it is terrible as it wobbles.
I need to add something behind it. Two options-
1. Glue it to plywood. Problem here is trying to get the plywood the same size as the chalkboard (i'm not a carpenter).
2. Glue some wood panels at the back - one at the top, middle and bottom and two in between at the edges. This is easier as I can cut the wood and clamp/glue to panels on the back.

Any other ideas (not framing) and would glue/clamp with pine and masonite  stick?

Comment: From the title I'd say just attach it to a wall... which you're planing on doing, so just do that. Or you were going to hang it like a picture? Nope. Predrill each corner at least an inch in and use screws.

Comment: Glue it directly to the wall with commercial grade construction adhesive; no drill, no screws. Or attach as suggested by @Mazura.

Comment: can't screw it - done that and the board is too wobbly. Lifts off the wall. Don't want to glue it to the wall as it is not long term.

Comment: I would then suggest option 1. I know you are not a professional carpenter but you can mark a straight line on plywood and cut it with a hand saw if you don't own or feel comfortable using a power saw. Just takes a bit of hard work and patience.